# Run complex SQL queries using python

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server

I am trying to run this SQL query by connecting pyodbc and SQL Server. The query selects columns from existing tables and performs a select into a global temp table.

```
sql_extract_query = """SELECT left(convert(varchar(8),dim_orderdate_key,112),6) as forYYYYMM,
CASE
    WHEN ForProfile IN ('AA','AB','AC','AD','AE') then 'Stage 1'
    WHEN ForProfile IN ('AF','AG','AH','AI') then 'Stage 2'
    
END AS VODAUK_Stage,  
hasPaymentOK, 
amount,
CASE    
    WHEN amount>0 AND amount <=50 THEN 'A £0000-£0050'
    WHEN amount>50  AND amount<=100 THEN 'B £0050-£0100'
    WHEN amount>100 AND amount<=150 THEN 'C £0100-£0150'
    WHEN amount>150 AND amount<=200 THEN 'D £0150-£0200'

    WHEN amount>2500 THEN 'I £2500+'     
END AS ABC_Amt_Bucket,
CustID,
sumPaymentPaidAmount

INTO ##tmpCaseResult
FROM db as CR WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join db.[ConsumerAccount] byConsAcc on byConsAcc.consumeraccount_key = [CR].consumeraccount_key  
inner join db.[CustomerAccount] byCustAcc on byCustAcc.customeraccount_key = [CR].customeraccount_key 
WHERE byCustAcc.ForCustomer = 'ABC' AND
[amount] > 0  AND
CR.orderdate_key >= cast(convert(char(6),dateadd(month,-18,getdate()),112)+'01' as int)
AND [ForProfile] like 'A%';"""
```

Wondering if there exist any ways to run this complex query? I have tried with pyodbc and pymssql, but the temp table was not created.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Likely the `##tmpCaseResult` table was created just fine, it just doesn't exist beyond the query because there are no spids requiring it.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning for your input. However, could you please elaborate on it.

Comment: Yes, the table gets created, but it just disappears as the program execution is completed. How do I resolve this? Because after the table creation, I want to perform aggregations using SQL query.

Comment: SQL Server cleans up #temp and ##temp tables as soon as there are no spids (connections) using them. They are usually scoped to whatever statement/stored procedure created them, so a common trick for longer-lifed temp tables is to create them in a top-level stored procedure then, from that stored procedure, call subordinate stored procedures that populate them, manipulate them and/or report on them.

Comment: Your Python statement creates and populates a ##temp table but then does nothing with it, and SQL Server cleans it up as soon as the connection is released back to the connection pool. You could select from the ##temp table at the end of your query if you want to return the results to Python.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Thanks a lot @AlwaysLearning!